# How to combine columns of two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three temporary columns,

1. `@Pid (PartyId bigint)` which contains All Partyid
2. `@t PartyID bigint,PartyName varchar(50)SaleQty decimal(18,2))` it contains 
   Sale history of All parties of financial year 15-16.
3. `@ty PartyID bigint,PartyName varchar(50)SaleQty decimal(18,2))` it contains 
   Sale history of All parties of financial year 16-17.

I want to combine two temporary table `@t` and `@ty` such a way that record of 
    any party id of both financial record should be in one row. And also if any 
    partyid does not have entry in anyone of the table `@t` and `@ty` then the 
    saleQty should be zero of in that financial year.

I have done following query to solve this.

```
select  A.PartyName,isnull(SUM(A.SaleQty),0) as TotalSale,isnull(SUM(B.SaleQty),0) as TotalSaleB  
from @t  A 
left join @ty B ON B.PartyId=A.PartyID
inner join @Pid P on P.PartyID=A.PartyID and B.PartyID=P.PartyID 
where PartyName like'%Jain'
group by A.PartyID,A.PartyName
```

My Output is

```
 PartyName               TotalSale(15-16)      TotalSale(16-17)   
 JAIN TRADERS (DHAMPUR) 16682.00                 9699.00
```

My Desired Result should be

```
 PartyName               TotalSale(15-16)      TotalSale(16-17)   
 JAIN TRADERS (DHAMPUR)   389.00                    139.00
 Sourav Traders           3899.00                   0.00
 Tickrej Traders         0.00                      0.00
```

But i am unable to get the desired result. Please Help me some one here.

Comment: please show current output and expected output

Comment: My Question Edited

Comment: Wouldn't you want the Total Sales for each FY? Combine both tables into a temp table with an added column FY. The left join that table from @Pid. Then you can get the total sales by FY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare  @Pid table (PartyId bigint)
insert into @Pid values (1)
insert into @Pid values (2)
insert into @Pid values (3)
insert into @Pid values (4)


declare @t table (PartyID bigint, PartyName varchar(50), SaleQty decimal(18,2))
insert into @t values(1, 'a', 10)
insert into @t values(1, 'c', 5)
insert into @t values(2, 'b', 10)
insert into @t values(4, 'b', 20)

declare @ty table(PartyID bigint,PartyName varchar(50), SaleQty decimal(18,2))
insert into @ty values(1, 'a', 10)
insert into @ty values(2, 'c', 15)
insert into @ty values(2, 'b', 10)


select c.PartyID as PartyID, ISNULL(sum(A.SaleQty), 0) as TotalSale15_16 into #A
from @t  A right join @Pid c on A.PartyID = c.PartyId
group by C.PartyID

select c.PartyID as PartyID,ISNULL(sum(B.SaleQty), 0) as TotalSale16_17 into #B
from @ty  B right join @Pid c on  B.PartyID = c.PartyId
group by C.PartyID

select A.PartyID, ISNULL(a.TotalSale15_16, 0) as TotalSale16_17, ISNULL(b.TotalSale16_17, 0) as TotalSale16_17 
from #A a join #B b on a.PartyID = b.PartyID

drop table #A
drop table #B


result:

PartyID TotalSale16_17  TotalSale16_17
1   15.00   10.00
2   10.00   25.00
3   0.00    0.00
4   20.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `@Pid` to be the "base" table, and left join both tables to it.
You also need to use `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL`) to get the party name from whatever temporary table it exists in.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.PartyName, B.PartyName), 
       COALESCE(SUM(A.SaleQty, 0)) TotalSale_t,
       COALESCE(SUM(B.SaleQty, 0)) as TotalSale_ty
FROM @Pid C
LEFT JOIN @t A ON C.PartyId = A.PartyId
LEFT JOIN @ty B ON C.PartyId = B.PartyId
GROUP BY A.PartyName, B.PartyName
```

Comment: this query is not sufficient because it may happens any partyid may have not does any business in any financial year then both totalSale_t and TotalSale_ty should be zero.

Comment: The both will be zero, note the use of coalesce. However, the party name will be null in that case.

Comment: But i want to show the party name is this possible.

Comment: is it possible to show the partyname also in all cases

Comment: You will only be able to show it if the party has at least one record in either `@t` or `@ty`.

Comment: The Above Query is giving the desired result because the Sale Quantity is not coming appropriate but it becomes more than that. Such as a party named 'Ansh General Sotres' has 2155 sale quantity in 15-16 financial year. but it is giving 249980. which is wrong.

Comment: I can't test without sample data, but I see that the problem is solved anyway, so...